# Not able to post data to web api controller action using FromBody Attribute

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Client Side model (Type Script File) :

```
export  interface IRecord {
    id: string
    amount: string,
    amountConst: string,
    amountLC: string,   
}
```

Server Side model/class : I am using newtonsoft json.

If i change the Json property value to name of property in typescript file then
that column value is not visible on UI.

```
public class Records
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [Column("Amount")]
    [JsonProperty("Amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    [Column("Amount Const $")]
    [JsonProperty("Amount Const $")]
    public string AmountConst { get; set; }

    [Column("Amount LC")]
    [JsonProperty("Amount LC")]
    public string AmountLC { get; set; }
}
```

Web Api Contoller :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Export")]
[ActionName("Export")]
public FileResult Export([FromBody]List<Records> Record)
{
    try
    {
    }
}
```

Server side I am getting the exact count of records from client side
but with null property values.

Comment: You should remove the `JsonProperty` everywhere and fix your bindings in angular to use the versions without an space. When you add `JsonProperty`with a space then ASP.NET Core expects an json body like `[{ "Amount": 5, "Amount Const $": "abc", "Amount LC": "xyz" }]` but your angular client sends `[{ "amount": 5, "amountConst": "abc", "amountLC": "xyz" }]` instead

Comment: @Tseng I am using contract resolver to convert property names to names in Typescript file,Pascalcase to  camelcase

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you should change either the way you send a client model or server-side bindings.

If you specify `[JsonProperty]` attribute, the JSON deserializer expects that the JSON property name will be exactly the same as the value of `propertyName` argument.

For your case the model you send should look like this

```
[{
    "ID": "11",
    "Amount": "1",
    "Amount Const $": "1.0",
    "Amount LC": "aaa"
}]
```

the interface `IRecord` can't be used since it couldn't be bound to a server-side model.

So, you have several options to make it work:

- drop `IRecord` interface and send the object with the structure like shown above
- change server-side model so both models' properties match
- write a custom Model binder for `Records` type (please [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding)) to handle your case